# Conventional method for socket based application protocol parsing

Tags: parsing, sockets, networking, network-protocols

What is the conventional way to parse an application protocol?

Given a stream from a socket of an already designed protocol (SMTP for example), what is the usual way to process the protocol. Is it a yacc based parser, a regex based approach or other way?

Comment: Question is a bit subjective but promises interesting answers, so +1. (I've seen mostly hand-made (non-yacc) parsers for things like SMTP)

Comment: Understood, but it is one case where I'd like to know the general approach that people use. We can gather all the methods here.

Comment: _"We can gather all the methods here."_ - that doesn't seem like an SO question. Anyhow, _"what is the usual way to process the protocol?"_: use a library.

Comment: If I have a custom protocol how does one parse the protocol in the library?

Comment: FWIW, I have never seen a communication's layer driven directly from a context-free parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many application layer protocols, but I think the main difference lies in whether it's **binary** or **text based**. Both are used extensively.

For a **text based protocol** it's quite usual to tokenize the input and then parse it with something like `yacc`. Some text based protocols are even easier to parse than that, so you might just split up the input and check whether it makes sense. Encoding should be taken into account, but it must be something you already have the routines for in your language via built-in methods or a library, e.g. `UTF-8`. HTTP, for instance is a text protocol, and is quite easy to parse (example from [here](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#sample)):

Request:

```
GET /path/file.html HTTP/1.0
From: someuser@jmarshall.com
User-Agent: HTTPTool/1.0
[blank line here]
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Fri, 31 Dec 1999 23:59:59 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1354

<html>
<body>
<h1>Happy New Millennium!</h1>
(more file contents)
  .
  .
  .
</body>
</html>
```

Most programmers can write a parser for that, even though you better rely on a well-tested and complete library implementation.

**Binary protocols** are somewhat different though. The first thing is to encode/decode the message using e.g. [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) (used very often in telecom), [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) or something similar. If possible, don't invent your own binary format, rely on tested and tried libraries - this is hard to get right, no wonder that e.g. for `ASN.1` most tools are expensive.

This is `ASN.1 UPER`, you define a simple element e.g. (example from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One#Example)):

```
myQuestion FooQuestion ::= {
    trackingNumber     5,
    question           "Anybody there?"
}
```

and it gets encoded like this:

```
01 05 0e 83 bb ce 2d f9 3c a0 e9 a3 2f 2c af c0
```

With all the bit-shifting and masking, it's not very easy to implement - that's why open source `ASN.1` libraries with `PER` support are so rare.

Both approaches have their advantages/disadvantages. Text based protocols are somewhat easier to get right, debug and understand. They are usually quite chatty, though, and under certain circumstances this matters a lot. This is when one chooses e.g. `ASN.1 PER`, which is very difficult to implement or debug, but very compact.